# Hellcarver Demon and Second Sunrise

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When [Hellcarver Demon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHellcarver%20Demon%5d)'s ability triggers and I sac all my permanents and discard my hand then cast [Second Sunrise](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSecond%20Sunrise%5d) do I have to keep track of the discarded cards? because second sunrise say s return to play all artifact, creature, enchantment and land cards that were put into the graveyard from play this turn. Since my hand was discarded I don't think it satisfies the second sunrise condition. I think I just answered my own question but I'll ask anyway to make sure I'm right.

Comment: As a general rule, gatherer has the most up to date wording on a card, and the text there should be looked at when you are unsure about the wording on your printed copy of the card.

Answer (score 5):

That's correct, the cards in your hand were not "in play", which is the old name for the battlefield. The current official text of Second Sunrise follows the modern wording:

> Each player returns to the battlefield all artifact, creature, enchantment, and land cards in his or her graveyard that were put there **from the battlefield** this turn.

The cards from your hand were not put into the graveyard *from the battlefield*.